# included js file didn't run when loaded

Tags: javascript, html, ampersand.js

I include with this, my app on page's header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.js"> </script>
```

And browser load it, but didn't run.
if I copy a response from server, and paste it to console it works fine. So.. what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate your file the right way.
The `/` will make it look at the root.

I suggest it maybe as that

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"> </script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bundle.js"> </script>
```

Comment: If it was helpful please consider marking it as a good answer ^_^

Comment: and try to provide us with more info to help you the right way

Answer (score 0):

With out knowing the folder structure of your app I would suggest:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"> </script>
```

The `/` will make it look at the root.